# Return a number of times of a specific string in python

Tags: python, string, counting

Return the number of times that the string "hi" appears anywhere in the given string.

```
count_hi('abc hi ho') → 1
count_hi('ABChi hi') → 2
count_hi('hihi') → 2
```

My code is below:

```
def count_hi(str): 
  sum = 0
  count = 1
   if "hi" in str:
    sum = sum + count
    count = 1 + count
   return count and sum
```

I'm trying to do it with character slicing. So I can test if there is a "h" and "i" in a word and counting the combination of "h" and "i" to make "hi" . So "hi" could be at the beginner, middle, and/or at the end of a bunch of words or letters and/ or by itself.

Comment: You don't have a loop - how could `sum` and `count` be anything other than `0` and `1` or `1` and `2`? This is on top of the syntax error in your function, with that unexpected indent. And you're also masking two built-ins.

Comment: what are you referring to when you mention built-ins?

Comment: Google "python built-in" for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `count()` function for the string.

```
>>> "abc hi ho".count("hi")
1
>>> "ABChi hi".count("hi")
2
```

Answer (score 0):

str.count(sub[, start[, end]])

Return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring sub in the range [start, end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation.